# Passing data via class PHP PDO

Tags: php, function, class, pdo

I started out with creating a connection to the database where I got data to be outputted into a HTML TABLE, all of that code is under "ALL CODE IN ONE FILE - THIS ONE WORKS". As it says in the title, it works exactly as it should. 

What I am trying to do now is to basically get the same output, but this time separate the code into three files, one for the connection, one for the class and function and one for HTML.

**PROBLEM:** I cannot pass the column "product_name" to the HTML table.

ERRORS i am getting: 
***"Notice: Undefined variable: v in /testTwo.php on line 22"*** 

and
 
***"Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /testTwo.php on line 22"***

Below is all of the code:

1 - ALL CODE IN ONE FILE - THIS ONE WORKS

(Same project but three files)
1 - configTest2.php (DB connection)

2 - classTwo.php (class and function)

3 - testTwo.php (HTML)

ALL CODE IN ONE FILE - THIS ONE WORKS

```
<html>
<body>


<?php

echo "<table style='border: solid 2px black; text-align:left;'>";
echo "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Price(From-To)</th><th>Stock</th></tr>";

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "name";

echo "<td>";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT product_name, product_quantity, product_id, product_price_lowest, product_price_highest FROM table ORDER BY product_price_lowest ASC, product_price_highest DESC ");
    $stmt->execute();

    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    foreach ($result as $v) {
      echo "<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid black;'>";
      echo "</td>";
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>' .$v->product_name. "</td>";
      echo '<td>' .$v->product_price_lowest. '-' .$v->product_price_highest.  "</td>";
      echo '<td>' .$v->product_quantity. "</td>";
      echo '</tr>';
     }
      echo "</td>";
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

**1 - configTest2.php (DB connection)**

```
<?php
session_start();
/* DATABASE CONFIGURATION */
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'name');
define("BASE_URL", "http://localhost/"); // Eg. http://yourwebsite.com



function getTestdb()
{
  $servername=DB_SERVER;
  $username=DB_USERNAME;
  $password=DB_PASSWORD;
  $dbname=DB_DATABASE;

try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
return $conn;
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

}
?>
```

**2 - classTwo.php (class and function)**

```
<?php

class classTwo
{
public function twoFunction(
  $productName,
  $productQty,
  $productId,
  $productLow,
  $productHigh)
{
  try {
$conn = getTestdb();
$stmt = $conn->prepare(
  "SELECT
  product_name =           :productName,
  product_quantity =       :productQty,
  product_id =             :productId,
  product_price_lowest =   :productLow,
  product_price_highest =  :productHigh

  FROM table
  ORDER BY product_price_lowest ASC, product_price_highest DESC
  ");
$stmt->bindParam("productName",  $productName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam("productQty",   $productQty,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam("productId",  $productId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam("productLow",   $productLow,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam("productHigh",    $productHigh,   PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach ($result as $v) {

echo $v->product_name;
echo $v->product_price_lowest; 
echo $v->product_price_highest;
echo $v->product_quantity;
}
}


}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
}
}
$conn = null;

?>
```

**3 - testTwo.php (HTML)**

```
<?php

include("configTest2.php");
include("classTwo.php");
$classTwo = new classTwo();

?>

<html>
<body>

<br>
<br>

    <table style='border: solid 2px black; text-align:left;'>
   <tr><th>Name</th><th>Price(From-To)</th><th>Stock</th></tr>
    <td>

<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid black;'>
</td>
<tr>
<td> <?php echo $v->product_name;?> </td>
<td>  </td>
<td>  </td>
<td> <button type="submit" onclick="askForSell">  Sell  </button>  </td>
<td> <button type="submit" onclick="askForBuy">   Buy   </button> </td>
</tr>


</td>
</table>

<br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're trying to use a variable called `$v` in `testTwo.php`, but never defined that variable.  The only variable defined there is `$classTwo`.  Did you mean to just call `twoFunction()` on `$classTwo`?

Comment: `$classTwo` is never used.

Comment: @David In this example I want the product name to show in the table in file testTwo.php. As it does in the foreach loop show in the "ALL CODE IN ONE FILE".

Comment: @Swift123: Well, that's not going to work this way.  Even if you do call the `twoFunction()` method, that method by itself just prints the values without any HTML around them.  Perhaps you want that method to *return* some object or array of values and then you want to print the data from that object?

Comment: @David: That is what I am trying to do but I cannot get a value. I tried as you can see to get values from the column "product_name" from the database table but it didn't work. Am I printing it wrong for the HTML table in testTwo.php?

Comment: @Swift123: Well, as the error tells you, in `testTwo.php` you're trying to print a variable that isn't defined.  So, yes, that part is at least wrong.  In order to print your output, you can't print all of the values and *then* print all of the HTML.  You have to mix the two.  I would recommend having the method *return* the data you need, and then store that returned value in `$v` in `testTwo.php` and then you can loop over the values in `$v`.